# Triangles in object mode, how to make them disappear?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have tried hundreds of times and different ways and no luck.

See my geometry , it  is a little door with round corners in another object.

No overlapping  vertices, set shaded to smooth, mesh looks OK but in object mode I see these ugly lines .

Please guide me in the right direction on how to make it look smooth.

Thank you!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If you show more of the screen with the mode .. then it will be easier to work with your question.  There is a user option.  Show all edges.  Please turn it off.  Sometimes a person may want to see all edges.  Apparently not you.  Of course the edges do not appear in the render ... Correct?

Comment: In the object panel you can choose Viewport Display ... there is a choice Wire and Display all edges.  Your exploration there should turn off the edges.

Comment: maybe share your object? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You see all edges in both objects and then third screenshot shows both objects in object mode. All Edges are are not clicked in Vieport display and it has no effect on what I see in object mode